# NHibernate join + coalesce

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

This is a simplified example of the actual schema, so please bear with me.  I have a table `foo` with an `id` and a `value` column.  There's also a `bar` table with a FK back to the `foo` table, and this table has an `extended_value` column.  I want to have Foo's class map left join Bar and try to use it's `extended_value` column if present, otherwise fall back to Foo's `value`.

Here's the SQL equivalent of what I need:

```
select coalesce(b.extended_value, f.value) as value
  from foo f
  left join bar b on (b.id = f.id)
```

I'm using Fluent on top of NHibernate.  This is what I've been attempting to use:

```
Join("bar", m =>
{
    m.Optional();
    m.KeyColumn("id");
    m.Map(foo => foo.Value).Formula("COALESCE(extended_value, value)");
});
```

But this is failing because the generated SQL is expecting both `extended_value` and `value` to be on the same table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice is to **not** do this in the mapping.

Map `foo.value` and `bar.extended_value` independently, and then use `coalesce` in your queries and/or create an unmapped property that uses the `??` operator.

Comment: Why do you recommend not mapping it that way?

Comment: IMO it's business logic which should reside in the business objects(Domain model) not the mappings because this property falls appart when there is no database and for this case there is no real performance benefit of doing this in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

i would use Diego Mijelshon advice but the following should work too

```
// FooMap
Map(foo => foo.Value).Formula("COALESCE((select b.extended_value from bar b WHERE b.id = id), value)");
```

Comment: I ended up going with Diego's advice and encapsulating that logic within the domain object.  Out of further curiosity, would the formula above result in an n+1 query?